# Using nouns to modify names/numbers, e.g. teacher Smith, candidate Smith and room 5

Tags: grammar

I would like to know the rules of putting a noun in front of a name and number. I am not sure if the sentences below are grammatically correct.

1. He's in the class of *teacher Smith*.
2. It's announced that *candidate Smith* and *candidate Baker* would be disqualified.
3. The director ordered to discontinue *product 00223* and *product 98860*

I somehow have the urge to

- add "the" in front of the nouns "teacher", "candidate" and "product"
- capitalize the first letter of the nouns like "Teacher", "Candidate" and "Product"

Thank you.

Comment: Some of this is cultural.

Answer (score 2):

(3) is fine (except that 'products 12345 and 98765' would be more likely).

In Britain (and probably other English-speaking countries) we wouldn't refer to someone as 'teacher Smith'. In a school, it would be 'He's in Mr Smith's class'.

A prefix to a name is only capitalised when it's an official title which is regarded as part of the name, like Doctor Smith or Professor Smith. This doesn't apply to *candidate.* So we might say

> It has been announced that the candidates Smith and Baker will be disqualified.

though it would probably be more natural to say

> It has been announced that John Smith and Mary Baker will be disqualified as candidates.

Comment: Mr Kane the citizen. Pat the postman. Mr Giles the farmer. Probably fairly unusual exceptions.